# how to add ==>cancel and return 'my homepage' <== link on checkout page?

Tags: paypal

I'm very new beginner on coding and paypal system.. and
currently opened new website, and used Paypal API on 'Cart'> '$Checkout'
If click 'Checkout', it links to paypal checkout page and shows up login to paypal for payment with our webpage LOGO on the top.

Problem is here that, i setup everything, on paypal account
1.It is Business Setup,
2.Profile and Setting > Selling tool, 
setting On in Auto return under Website preferences and also URL and service name.

But still does not show up on bottom of paypal checkout page.

Is there any correct way to add "Cancel and Return (mypage)" link

or do i have to input specific code in API? Is there something else I need to set?

Please let me know how to do it..

Answer (score 0):

Have you sent it the url to use for a cancelled transaction? Here is my web.config section and it is not totally configured with correct information but you will need it either in a web.config or in webpage somewhere. These values are what are sent when a buyer clicks on "Buy with paypal" or whatever you want to call it:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true"/>

    <add key="business" value="xxxxxxxxx"/>

    <add key="IsSandbox" value="true"/>
    <add key="currency_code" value="USD"/>
    <add key="return" value="http://localhost/PayPal/RedirectFromPaypal"/>
    <add key="cancel_return" value="http://localhost/PayPal/CancelFromPayPal"/>
    <add key="notiry_url" value="http://localhost/PayPal/NotifyFromPayPal"/>

    <add key="test_url" value="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"/>
    <add key="Prod_url" value="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"/>

  </appSettings>
```